# How to set the value of a text input with MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools, forms, html-input

I have just begun playing with MooTools, and I don't understand why the following happens:

```
var input = new Element('input');
input.set('type','text');
input.set('value','this is the value');
console.log(input);
```

results in: `<input type=​"text">​`, so setting the `value` hasn't worked.

But if I do this:

```
var input = new Element('input');
input.set('type','text');
input.set('someValue','this is the value');
console.log(input);
```

I get the expected result of `<input type=​"text" somevalue=​"this is the value">​`.

Am I overlooking something, is what I am trying to do not allowed, is this a bug in Chrome (11.0.696.71, OS X) or am I doing something else wrong?

**Update:** thanks for your answer! You are right, the value is actually being set; `console.log(input.get('value'))` gives back the proper value and I can see the value in the input field when I append the input object to the DOM.

Apparently, the value setting is just not reflected as an attribute of the HTML element, but only stored internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the value isn't being set?

What do you get when you call: `input.get('value')`

I tested this (in firefox) and even though the console just logs `<input type=​"text">` the value does in fact get set. Try adding the element to the page and you'll see it :)

Comment: Was just going to say the same thing with my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyheiler/d27gv/)

Comment: Yep, that was the case. Now I'm curious; is this MooTools, or standard JavaScript behavior? Will leave that for some other time to find out :). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with this 'red herring' which I've since solved, and thought I'd share. 
I'm trying to make certain cells of a table row editable when the user clicks on the row:

```
var cells = this.getElements("td");
for (var ix=0;ix<cells.length; ix++){
   if (cells[ix].hasClass("edType_text")){
      var celltext = cells[ix].get("text");
      cells[ix].set('text','');
      var editTag = new Element ('input',{type:'text','value':celltext});
      editTag.inject(cells[ix]); 
   }
}
```

This seemed to work OK but when I clicked on the cell I couldn't edit it. Firebug and Chrome tools showed the added input tag as

```
<input type='text'>
```

instead of the expected:

```
<input type='text' value='xxxxxx' />
```

However this is perfectly normal as commented on above.

Spotted the 'deliberate' error ?

Of course when I clicked on the input field it triggered the mouse event on the row again, thus preventing me getting at the input!!!! :-{

To avoid this just add this line of code at the end of the if block:

```
editTag.addEvent("mousedown",function(event){event.stopPropagation();});
```