# Missing value attribute when injecting text input using mootools

Tags: mootools, element, code-injection

As noted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222062/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-text-input-with-mootools) question and in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Me7Zr/3/) fiddle, when injecting an input the value attribute doesn't seem to be added to the DOM, MooTools seems to handle it internally. Unfortunately this means that an input injected thus:

```
new Element("input", {type: "text", value: "injected value"}).inject(parent);
```

can't be selected like so:

```
parent.getElements('input[value="injected value"]').length;
```

(this returns 0 instead of 1 as it would if the value attribute was present)

In my project I need to insert blank input boxes but only if there isn't already a blank one;`if(parent.getElements('input[value=""]').length == 0`)however this is always resolving to true no matter how many blank inputs there are.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal or is there a fix for what seems like a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding:

```
var x = new Element("input", {type: "text", value: "injected value"}).inject(parent);
x.setAttribute("value",x.value);
```

**Caveat:** While this fixes your issue with the element's value attribute not being reflected, the value attribute is typically not a good way to check if a field is empty, because it is not sync'd with the input's contents.

It would be better to use something like this:

```
$$('input[type=text]').filter(function(item){return (item.value=="");})
```